# Can Google Scholar be a valid measure of citaiton?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Google Scholar provides number of citations for the paper,
but it sometimes includes non-academic paper, not peer-reviewed papers.
Is number of citation measured by Google Scholar accepted a reliable measure of citation by academic community?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is number of citation measured by Google Scholar accepted a reliable measure of citation by academic community?

Everybody knows that Google Scholar numbers measure the activity of a person only approximately. On the other hand, all the other numbers (say, the Hirsch indices) also apply only approximately. So not by itself, but in combination with other parameters Google Scholar is very useful. Besides, people do not usually refer to not refereed papers unless the papers are very recent.

Also it is not clear what you mean by "academic community". These numbers are important for administrators in the hiring/promotional cases. Department colleagues usually do not need these numbers.